# (Notepad++)Remove lines which doesn't meet password policy

Tags: notepad++, password-policy

The Password Policy:

Each password should have at least 3 of these:

1. Contain `Numbers`
2. Contain `a-z`
3. Contain `A-Z`
4. Contain `special characters !@#$%^&*()_+`

For example, this list:

```
12345678
adfghj
AASDFGHJ
!@#$%^&
1234as
1234ASDF
1345!#$%
asdfg!@#$
ASDFGB!#$$
SSRasd
Goodone123
G00done!@#
1@a
Aa1
```

Should be like this:

```
Goodone123
G00done!@#
1@a
Aa1
```

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what regex can *match* your passwords:

```
^                                             # Start of line
 (?:                                          # Start of the alternation group
   (?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])             # Conditions 1, 2, 3
   |
   (?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])    # Conditions 1, 2, 4
   |
   (?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])    # Conditions 1, 3, 4
   | 
   (?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+]) # Conditions 2, 3, 4
   | 
   (?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+]) # Conditions 1, 3, 4
 )
 .*                                           # The line itself is matched
$                                             # Up to the end of line
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qA9kE1/1)

To invert it, we just need to convert the non-capturing *alternation* group above to a *negative lookahead* by a mere replacing the `:` with `!`:

```
^                          # Start of line
 (?!                       # A negative lookahead
```

See the [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/qA9kE1/2)

To use this in Notepad++, **check *`Match case`* option**, and **add `\R*` at the end of the pattern** to also remove linebreaks after the removed lines. A one-line for use in NPP:

```
^(?!(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])).*$\R*
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

See npp regex below. *Note: Ensure `Match Case` and `Wrap Around` is checked and `Regular expression` is selected*

```
^[^\d\l]+$|^[^\d\u]+$|^[^\d\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+]+$|^[^\l\u]+$|^[^\l\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+]+$|^[^\u\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+]+$
```

The regex matches all possible combinations of two missing password criteria:

1. Missing digit and lowercase letter
2. Missing digit and uppercase letter
3. Missing digit and special character
4. Missing lowercase letter and uppercase letter
5. Missing lowercase letter and special character
6. Missing uppercase letter and special character

**UPDATE**
Notepad++ reference [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Please explain what each character does, even if it will take time.

Comment: @AbAppletic See reference article, no need to repeat information here